# sed, replacing first occurrence match of the first line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

my text looks like below

```
this This that
it It Its
my My Mine
this This that
it It Its
my My Mine
```

I want to replace the first line of the first occurrence match. eg. match the line which contains `my` then replace the line. I did

```
cat txt|sed "0,/my/c\my changed line" txt
```

The print off looks below, the first 2 line are trimmed.

```
my changed line
this This that
it It Its
my My Mine
```

if I run this `cat txt|sed "s/my/changeline/" txt`

The output is below

```
this This that
it It Its
changeline My Mine
this This that
it It Its
changeline My Mine
```

How can I get the result like below?

```
this This that
it It Its
changeline My Mine
this This that
it It Its
my My Mine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '0,/.*my.*/s//my changed line/' file
```

What this does,
in the range of `0,/.*my.*/` it will replace the matched `.*my.*` with "my changed line".

An equivalent slightly easier to understand version of the same thing:

```
sed '0,/my/{/.*my.*/s//my changed line/}' file
```

Using `awk` the logic is slightly easier to understand:

```
awk '!/my/ || seen { print } /my/ && !seen { print "my changed line"; seen = 1 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/my/ && !f++{$0="changeline My Mine"} 1' file
this This that
it It Its
changeline My Mine
this This that
it It Its
my My Mine
```